# html5 audio in IE9 wont play

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-9

I have an example here:

http://www.interactivepixel.net/ha/index.html

(If you view the source this is all the code and I have)

Note: I have only placed mp3 file on the server so it wont play in firefox (or other browsers than need ogg format)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm on a mac, I cannot give it a try, but here an idea.

Have you tried using the Audio constructor?

```
var audio = new Audio('adg3com_bustedchump.mp3');
audio.play();
```

You can then add the event listeners you want to this object. There's a lot going on there that looks pretty redundant.

Comment: Have you got more example of code created with Audio constructor? Binding to events, playing, seeking, etc... I never used it like that, just with creating the iframe dynamically. Thanks

Comment: Well, it basically creates a new <audio>-element, so you can use all the methods you can use on such an element.

Seeking, for example, would look like:
    audio.currentTime = 11.5;
to jump 11 and a half second into the file.

Comment: Oh, and I didn't know one could run IE on a mac? Is it possible without virtual machines?

Comment: Why wouldnt you be able to run ie on mac? As far as I know it runs normally.

Comment: On the IE9 download page it says "To get our latest browser, you need to be running Windows Vista or Windows 7.", so I don't know :)